# How to record a function is executed and not to run it again over the same DIV using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my few carousel slides I am converting a DIV's pixel value to Percentage.

```
$('#carousel-lesson-slide').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

//  convert to percentage
  function convert_to_percentage(el){
    var parent = el.parent();
    el.css({
      left:parseInt(el.css('left'))/parent.width()*100+"%",
      top: parseInt(el.css('top'))/parent.height()*100+"%",
      width: el.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
      height: el.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
    });
  }

  if ($('.droppable-icon-on-img-wrap').is(":visible")) {
    $(".dropped-icon-holder").each(function(){
      convert_to_percentage($(this))
    });
  }

  if ($('.droppable-label-on-img-wrap').is(":visible")) {
    $(".dropped-label-holder").each(function(){
      convert_to_percentage($(this))
    });
  }

});
```

**So, my question is:** How can I avoid converting the `.dropped-icon-holder` and `.dropped-label-holder` width to percentage again and again while switching between the slides.

Please Note: `.dropped-icon-holder` and `.dropped-label-holder` will come in more than one slide but once they are converted pixel to percentage value then again the conversion should not happen. I need to keep every line of code within `slid.bs.carousel` because to get the `.dropped-icon-holder` and `.dropped-label-holder` parent's width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a flag for each element, using `data()`, when the function is initially called for it. Check that flag and only continue the function if it is false:

```
function convert_to_percentage(el){
    if(el.data('converted')) return;

    var parent = el.parent();
    el.css({
        left:parseInt(el.css('left'))/parent.width()*100+"%",
        top: parseInt(el.css('top'))/parent.height()*100+"%",
        width: el.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
        height: el.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
    }).data('converted', true);
}
```

Comment: that's working and as expected :) thank you.
Now the title of this ticket doesn't make much sense, the title need to be changed to something else :) Just curious to know is it possible to  know if a DIV width is set in Percentage or Pixel using jQuery ?

Comment: @Syed No, not reliably AFAIK.

Comment: I got it answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250918/how-to-know-if-a-div-width-is-set-in-percentage-or-pixel-using-jquery